# Replacing the dex file in the application

Tags: android, directory, dex

Is it possible without root, get access to classes.dex file in my application, and replace it with another file in background process? If possible, methods, please.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091006/delta-update-for-android-app-updates/49546245#49546245) ?

Comment: @Sagar when linking to your own answers, please mention that the answer is yours so that it doesn't look like you're trying to gather more rep. Something like "have you seen my answer here <link>" would be more appropriate.